# Generate all n - bit sequences with all unique k-bit subsequences.

Tags: algorithm, bit

I found this problem:

> Consider sequences of 36 bits. Each such sequence has 32 5 - bit
>   sequences consisting of adjacent bits. For example, the sequence
>   1101011… contains the 5 - bit sequences 11010,10101,01011,…. Write a
>   program that prints all 36 - bit sequences with the two properties: 
>   1.The first 5 bits of the sequence are 00000. 
>   2. No two 5 - bit subsequences are the same.

So I generalized to find all n-bit sequences with k - bit unique subsequences satisfy the above requirements. However, the only approach I can think of is using a brutal force search: generate all permutations of n-bit sequence with the first k bits zero, then for each sequence, check if all k-bit subsequences are unique. This apparently is not a very efficient approach. I am wondering is there a better way to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach seems to be a backtracking approach.  You can keep track of which 5-bit sequences you've seen with a flat array.  At each bit, try adding 0 -- `counter = (counter & 0x0f) << 1` and check if you've seen that before, then do a `counter = counter | 1` and try that path.

There are probably more efficient algorithms that can prune the search space faster.  This seems related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence.  I am not certain, but I believe that it is actually equivalent; that is, the last five digits of the sequence will have to be `10000`, making it cyclic.

EDIT: here's some c code.  Less efficient than it could be in terms of space, because of the recursion, but simple.  The worst bit is the mask management.  It appears I was correct about De Bruijn sequences; this finds all 2048 of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *binprint(int val) {
    static char res[33];
    int i;
    res[32] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        res[31 - i] = (val & 1) + '0';
        val = val >> 1;
    }
    return res;
}

void checkPoint(int mask, int counter) {
    // Get the appropriate bit in the mask
    int idxmask = 1 << (counter & 0x1f);

    // Abort if we've seen this suffix before
    if (mask & idxmask) {
        return;
    }

    // Update the mask
    mask = mask | idxmask;

    // We're done if we've hit all 32
    if (mask == 0xffffffff) {
        printf("%10u 0000%s\n", counter, binprint(counter));
        return;
    }

    checkPoint(mask, counter << 1);
    checkPoint(mask, (counter << 1) | 1);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    checkPoint(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution. It took me some time to understand your method, so I'll add some comments to help others. The "flat array" mentioned above consists of the 32 5-bit subsequences. Therefore this can efficiently be represented by a 32-bit bitfield, which is what the `mask` variable is. That is, once a 5-bit value is placed into the 5 right-most bits of `counter` (e.g. `01101`) then the corresponding bit (e.g. `13`) is set in `mask`. This is how you both track repeats (`if(mask & idxmask) return;`) and when you are finished (`if(mask==0xffffffff)`).

Answer (score 2):

I remember seeing this exact problem in a programming interview questions book of mine. Here is their solution:

[image: Explanation of Algorithm 2]

[image: Algorithm 2 - Unique 5-bit Sequences]

hope it helps. cheers.

Comment: You seem to have cut out all the parts explaining what's going on.

Comment: This is just the algorithm, i screen capped it. The explanation is on another page. Ill grab it and edit this post. give me a minute.

Comment: That's exactly where I saw the question, but I probably didn't get the answer correctly. Still thanks. :)